# Is it possible to set the size of an array within structure during runtime?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a structure as below:

```
struct Query {  
    int     pages[];
    int     currentpage;
};
```

I was wondering if it was possible to set the size of this array after creating the structure.

```
Query new = malloc(sizeof(struct Query));
```

After this, I will perform some calculations which will then  tell me the size that `pages[]` needs to be. If `pages[]` needed to be of size 4, how can I set it as such?

Comment: `int pages[];`  --> `int *pages;` and then `malloc`-ate it. Remember that pages have to be `free`ed before the whole structure `free`.

Comment: in other languages, you can create a constructor for a struct. not sure with c. but i think that is the path to take.

Comment: Let `pages` be an int pointer instead. That way you can allocate memory for it in the heap with malloc after you've created the struct.

Comment: This struct is illegal. Flexible array member must be the last element. Then you can adjust the size .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the type of `pages` member to pointer.

```
struct Query {  
    int *pages;
    int currentpage;
};

struct Query *test = malloc(sizeof(struct Query));

if (test != NULL)
{
   //your calculations

   test->pages = malloc(result_of_your_calcs);
   if (test->pages != NULL)
   {
      // YOUR STUFF
   }
   else
   {
      // ERROR
   }
}
else
{
   // ERROR
}
```

When you'll `free` your struct, you have to do that on the contrary.

```
free(test->pages);
free(test);
```

Comment: I think you meant `if (test->pages == NULL) { /* ERROR */ }`, not error if `test->pages != NULL`

Answer (score 14):

In C99 you can use [Flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
struct Query {  
    int currentpage;
    int pages[]; /* Must be the last member */
};

struct Query *new = malloc(sizeof(struct Query) + sizeof(int) * 4);
```

Comment: OP said that wants to allocate the struct and after some calcs allocate the array. You should add a `realloc` example. BTW flexible arrays must be used by "expert" people, my personal opinion.

Comment: @LPs, I think you are right, but `realloc`ing with a different size (than the first `malloc`) seems dangerous to me, isn't it? For this concrete case, I think OP means allocate the struct without knowing the size of array at runtime (there is only an `int` and an array in the `struct` and the `int currentPage` can be stored in a temporary variable before `malloc` and then reassigned to the `struct`), but I could be wrong. Excuse my poor english.

Comment: I agree. This specific case can work as you described. I don't think that `realloc` can be more dangerous than using `malloc`. I mean: you have to know what you are doing using Flexible arrays. +1

Answer (score 5):

You can use a **Flexible array member** (details in [@AlterMann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37178989/3049655)) (**C99+**), or a **Zero length** array (**GNU C**).

Quoting from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html,

> Zero-length arrays are allowed in GNU C. They are very useful as the last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object:
>
> ```
> struct line {
>    int length;
>    char contents[0];
> };
>
> struct line *thisline = (struct line *)
>    malloc (sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
> thisline->length = this_length;
> ```

For standard C90, the linked site mentions

> In ISO C90, you would have to give `contents` a length of 1, which means either you waste space or complicate the argument to `malloc`.

This means that for the code to work in standard C90/C89, `char contents[0];` should be `char contents[1];`.

Comment: GCC supports flexible array member so there is not really any reason to use the zero-sized array.  And you don't need to cast maloc

Comment: Yes. But flexible array member is standard only in C99+ (Yes, I know C89 is ancient, but it is worth mentioning). And as for the cast, I just copied the code from the linked site as such (I know that the cast is not required)

Comment: @M.M: Zero-sized arrays had some advantages over flexible array members in some implementations that allowed them.  For example, if a programmer was mindful of alignment, given `struct SIZED_ARRAY {int size; int dat[0];} it would be possible to create an initialized instance via `struct { SIZED_ARRAY arr; int dat[4];} my_array = {{4}, {1,2,3,4}};`.  While some C99 compilers offer useful extensions, I don't think C99 itself offers any practical equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to use pointers to `int` instead of array.

You will need to change :

```
int pages[];
```

to :

```
int *pages;
```

and then dynamically allocate it like this :

```
Query *new = malloc(sizeof(struct Query));
if (new == NULL)
    printf ("Error\n");
else
{
    new->pages = malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    if (new->pages == NULL)
       printf ("Error\n");
}
```

---

Otherwise if you want to keep your format, you will use C99 mode. Declare `pages` as the last member of your struct, like this :

```
struct Query {  
    int currentpage;
    int pages[];
};
```

and then do :

```
Query *new = malloc(sizeof(struct Query) + 4*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Query * new  = ...` ?

Comment: @Shreevardhan yes, I missed the asterisk! Thanks, I edited my post :)

Comment: `new->pages = malloc(4*sizeof(int));` will cause a segmentation fault if the previous `malloc` for `new` fails.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as pointer and use `malloc` afterwards

```
struct Query {  
    int * pages;
    int   currentpage;
};

. . .

struct Query obj;
obj.pages = malloc(n * sizeof(int));   // n is the length you want
```